# My Stop Loss isn't working properly... I'm not sure what's wrong. This is Pine Script V5

Tags: pine-script

[Stop Loss didnt stop the trade. so it waits for trade to come into profity.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XNLg9.jpg)

My stop seems to work fine... But sometimes it just doesn't. I'm not sure what the issue is but I'm sure an experienced pine scripted can see the problem instantly.
Do you mind having a look? Thanks in advance. I tried several things already but I'm lost.
I included the code and photo link.
You can see from the photo that sometimes a trade is not stopped, instead it resorts to waiting until the market has come back up to the same price to stop it.

```
//Stop Loss Option//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
usestoploss = input(true, title="Use Stop Loss")
stoplosspercent = input.float(title="Stop Loss (%)", defval=-0.7, minval=-50, maxval=0, 
    step=.1) / 100
stoploss = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + stoplosspercent)
stop = stoploss > close and stoploss[1] < close[1] and usestoploss
```

Comment: If you need to see more code just let me know.

Comment: Can you provide your full code and the ticker id, timeframe, date, time etc. where this happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to figure it out. Sorry Baris Yakut, I did not see your comment reply.
Here is my code for stop loss and take profit in a V5 strategy.

```
//INPUTS, an inputs to turn them on or off, and inputs to adjust the 
// percentage.
usetakeprofitoption = input(true,  title="Use Take Profit", group=" 
    ", tooltip=ttusetakeprofit)
takeprofitpercent   = input.float(title="Take Profit (%)", defval=11.5,  
    minval=0,   maxval=1000, step=.1, group=" ", 
    tooltip=tttakeprofitpercent) / 100
usestoplossoption   = input(true,  title="Use Stop Loss", group=" 
    ", tooltip=ttusestoploss)
stoplosspercent     = input.float(title="Stop Loss (%)", defval=-7.5,  
    minval=-50, maxval=0,    step=.1, group=" ", 
    tooltip=ttstoplosspercent) / 100

//CONDITIONS, if the position entry price goes up or down to one of 
// these levels then it will exit the trade.
take       = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + takeprofitpercent)
takeoption = take < close and usetakeprofitoption

stop       = strategy.position_avg_price * (1 + stoplosspercent)
stopoption = stop > close and usestoplossoption

sell = takeoption or stopoption
```